# MS Access: field separator contains multiple characters

Tags: ms-access

I exported a table with R using the following code:

```
dat <- data.frame(n = seq(1, 19, by = 1),
des = c("Some. very long text", "Some very; lang test", "Some, vary long text", "Some veri long$ text", "Another very #long text", "Anather very +long text", "Another- very long text", "Different_ text", "Diferent* text", "More { text", "More] test", "Much& more§~ text", "Muh more text", "Some other long text", "Some otoher long text", "Some more text", "Same more text", "New text", "New texd"))

write.table(dat, "path/datex.txt", sep=".;$.", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Within the column "des" there are all kinds of characters used. It is not possible to use a single eparation character as _,;§ or any other. Now I have the problem, that MS Access doesn't allow to multiple charcters as a field separator. How can I Import a txt file with multiple charcters as field separator? I don't know VBA yet, so this would be a very time-consuming option.
Thanks.

Comment: As you are in control of the R code, modify this to use a single character as the separator.

Comment: This is not possible because all kinds of characters are used within the text in column "des". Within the textfield there would be recognized a new column.

Comment: Then have to use code to parse the file. This will not be fun, so find a local freelancer to carry out the task.

Comment: Instead of using a text file as an intermediate, why don't you use [the RODBC library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf) to connect directly from R to Access? You can use the sqlSave() function to write to a table in the database. Alternatively, you can write some VBA to read each line of the text file and split at each separator using [the split function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php).